# uiscrollview multiple uiview with zoom

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I'am working on an iPad application which can visualise network graphs with nodes and edges. This have I accomplished by using an UIScrollView and added UIViews as subviews for the nodes and CAShapeLayer as edges. This works ok with panning and tapping on nodes and uiscrollview, but now I want to implement zooming. This is where my problems begin. How am I supposed to use the UIScrollView with multiple UIView that should zoom in or out according to pinching? How should I limit the zooming to fit the UIScrollViews content size?
I have managed to create a structure as following:

[image]

Where the View under the scrollview function as a content view.
I add subviews to the content view programmatically so it would look like:

```
 View
     Scroll View (UIScrollView)
         View (UIView)
             >> Node1 (UIView)
             >> Node2 (UIView)
             >> Node3 (UIView)
```

The nodes works fine and can be dragged around. The problem (just to repeat my self) is that I can't control the content view according to the uiscrollview. I have tried to implement pinch gesture which works, but jumps up every time you begin a pinch. Further I have tried to implement a pan gesture but it will only work on the scrollview not on the content view.

I hope you guys can understand my problem. If you could help me to understand the structure of the views and where I should use gestures for pinch and panning I would really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am begining implementing some similar graph handling visualization. 
I Assume, that solution will be a little more tricky, than simply uiview with nodes.
I think, there will be some OpenGL handling panning, taping and zooming in-out. - something with SpriteKit or SceneKit, i guess.  I have seen he video from WWDC 2012, 2013, or 2014 - I don`t remember, where they showed how to deal with OpenGL and scrollviews.

Or it will be scrollview **only to recieve touches**, and some other view to **handle animation** for theese touch-drag-pinch events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Massmaker. I have made an app which can visualises hundreds of nodes at the same time using UIViews as nodes. This have i accomplished using only uiscrolliviews with uiviews as subviews. With this I can pan on the scrollview and drag and tap on nodes. Now I also want to zoom in an out and this is where I can't figurer out the structure of the views when I have multiple UIView s in the scrollview I want to resize properly like zooming. If you found the video please let me know.

Comment: Hello back. I've done parent UIView in scrollView - and into it I add my Nodes.  This parent UIView is object to pass in scrollView's delegate method  `viewForZoomingInScrollView`.